# Using Netbeans to design GUIs and the ability to start with Web Start

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans, java-web-start

I designed a GUI program using Netbeans 6.5 on a computer running Vista.  I uploaded it to my server and tested out the web start.  It worked fine.

Later when using a Mac, it was not able to work.  I tested it out in Ubuntu and was unsuccessful as well.  I even tried to compile the source code on Ubuntu and I got this:

Task required to generate JNLP file is missing, probably the library 'JWS Ant Tasks' is missing either from shared folder or from IDE installation.

Basically the Java Desktop Application ran fine on the Windows computer but will not run on other computers.  I just created a test Application on the Ubuntu computer, uploaded it and it ran fine.

How come the program I compiled and ran yesterday on a computer running Vista will not run on Ubuntu?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you might be having 64 bit JRE there on Ubuntu. Use 32 bit JRE, as far as I know JWS doesn't work with 64 bit.

Use the argument `java-vm-args` if you are having both 64 and 32 bit versions. Below is the example.

`<j2se version="1.5+" initial-heap-size="128m" max-heap-size="256m" java-vm-args="-d32"/>`